# Angular 9 introduced a global '$localize()' function that needs to be loaded

Tags: angular, localization, angular9

I'm getting the following error in my new angular project setup.

[Installed Packages and its versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fb18.png)

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: It looks like your
>   application or one of its dependencies is using i18n. Angular 9
>   introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
>   Please add `import '@angular/localize';` to your polyfills.ts file.
>   Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is
>   using i18n. Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that
>   needs to be loaded.

Note: I came from the following. It suggests falling back to old version.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32508

Comment: What is your question, exactly? The error message gives clear instructions on what to do.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the @angular/localize package first:

`npm install @angular/localize --save`

Then, `import '@angular/localize/init'` in your **polyfills.ts** file just like the error says

Comment: I get this error when running unit tests with Jest after adding a postinstall step for ngcc, as suggested by this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63727427. @angular/localize is a dependency in my package.json, and the @angular/localize/init is an import in my polyfills.ts, but same error on most test suites. I am running Angular 9. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Meh sorry just found the answer if anyone else has this issue - https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/678#issuecomment-755903805

Comment: For me I needed to use the `--skip-confirmation` flag: `npm install @angular/localize --skip-confirmation --save`. Otherwise I got [an error](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21512) "No terminal detected. '`--skip-confirmation`' can be used to bypass installation confirmation. Ensure package name is correct prior to '`--skip-confirmation`' option usage."

Answer (score 50):

The best way if you are using Angular CLI is to  run

`ng add @angular/localize`

It will take care of it automatically

Or else

`import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts`

Tested with `Angular 9`

Comment: does it automatically add it to the package.json with 'ng add...'?

Answer (score 15):

If you have many angular projects in same workspace, running 
`ng add @angular/localize`
will add import statement `import '@angular/localize/init'`
to polyfills.ts in default Project only,i think this will be fixed in later updates.

so you need to add `import '@angular/localize/init'` manually to polyfills.ts in other projects.

Comment: Underrated answer. This is never mentioned on the official guides.

Comment: I suspect this answer may have saved my day and my sanity.

Comment: In my case also ng add didn't add it to polyfills.ts. Thanks for this.

Comment: This answer saved me days. My default project already had the import, so the CLI report was very misleading: "Skipping installation: Package already installed Nothing to be done."

Comment: Is it possible to know what part/lib of my application depends on i18n?

Answer (score 8):

This error started to appear after I upgraded a large Nx/Angular CLI application with multiple sub apps to Angular 10. The solution suggested in the error (Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI) does not work if the application contains multiple apps. Each of these auto-generated app had its own `polyfill.ts`. I manually added the import (`import '@angular/localize/init';`) in each of the polyfill.ts file. To fix same error while running unit tests, I also had to add the import in test.ts file of libs.

Comment: I wish this answer was higher, this was exactly the problem I had with inner libs and had to add the import in the test.ts or it won't budge.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! This is the answer for in NX!

Answer (score 6):

If you are running `ng test` and the above answer doesn't work, install the package and add

`import "@angular/localize/init"`

to `polyfills-test.ts`

Comment: Good point here, also a setup with a specific ts file for tests. Need to be updated as well

Answer (score 6):

You have to add this package

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

then add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `ployfills.ts`

**But** if your **tests** that are failing in a library, you must add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `test.ts`

Comment: Im still getting that error, Ive removed the extension and cleaned the cache and %appdata% folder too :(

Answer (score 5):

Angular 9 introduced a global $localize() function that needs to be loaded if you use i18n.

Run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.

Then make sure you have:
- `@angular/localize` as a dependency in your app's package.json
- `import '@angular/localize/init'` in your polyfills.ts

Answer (score 5):

run

```
npm install @angular/localize --save
```

Then, in your `polyfills.ts`

```
import '@angular/localize/init'
```

this works for me

Answer (score 5):

I had this error while updating Angular version from 12 to 13. I followed the instructions:

1. Run ng add @angular/localize
2. import '@angular/localize/init' in your polyfills.ts

but it did not work for me. I already had @angular/localize in my modules and the import in the polyfills.ts file, after all my Angular 12 app was working fine.

To solve the issue, **I had to update the "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" version**. I hope this suggestion can save some headache to someone, given that there was no apparent link between the outdated @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap version and the error description.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is by using Angular CLI:

You just have to run the following command in terminal:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

It will automatically install packages and will also add the import statement in polyfills.ts file.

The import statement is:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

If you don't want to go through the CLI approach then you can manually enter the import statement in the polyfills.ts file.
Also you have to do one more step is to add the below line in package.json under dependencies tag.

```
"dependencies":{
    ...
    "@angular/localize":"^9.1.0",
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this error appeared when running `npm test` so the solutions above did not help. To solve it I had to import localize in the `jest.ts` file.
Just add:

```
import "@angular/localize/init";
```

Answer (score 2):

As the i18n attributes are now converted to $localize calls in the generated code, we need to load the $localize function.

The CLI offers a schematic to do this for you. Simply run:
ng add @angular/localize

It will add the package to your dependencies and the necessary import to your polyfills (import '@angular/localize/init')

You can also refer to the following link for more explanation. 
https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @THess thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the answer and shared the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my operating system because of this problem. And yesterday I found the cause of this problem. I was getting this issue due to a plugin I installed in Visual Studio Code. If you are using Angular9, do not install the first two plugins. You can install the third one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, in my case I try to use @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap for Angular v15.

After long investigation, I created new project with Angular v14:

```
npx -p @angular/cli@14.2.0 new hello-world
```

and install

```
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

And I worked!

So, I created polyfills.ts in root /src folder.

Then update angular.json:

```
projects/architect/build/polyfills: ["zone.js", "src/polyfills.ts"],
```

and

```
projects/architect/test/polyfills: ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing", "src/polyfills.ts"],
```

in tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts" <- add this
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

the same in tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "@angular/localize"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/polyfills.ts" <- add this
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes that is it, it works for Angular 16.2.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

replace this in polyfil:

```
import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';
```

with this :

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

and everything is OK !

Answer (score 0):

This error message may appear as well when you are switching to a different i18n library and have not cleaned up the project properly, such as removing all the occurrences of **i18n** in case you used the default **@angular/localize** package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `import '@angular/localize/init';` on the `polyfill.ts` file but the error was somewhere else! I Just drop it here in case it helps someone!

I have a `.browserlistrc` file on my project and the set of rules just broke Angular i18n. In my case, i had to remove the `>0.3%` from the list in order to get it working!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular Universal(SSR) then just add `import '@angular/localize/init';` on line 1. in server.ts file

That's it.