# "ERROR in getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected AngularFireModule to have an inner class declaration"

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angular9

```
Terminal -

    "WARNING in Invalid constructor parameter decorator in D:/New folder/SilverLife/node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:
     () => [
        { type: Object, decorators: [{ type: Inject, args: [PLATFORM_ID,] }] }
    ]
    
    ERROR in getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected
    AngularFireModule to have an inner class declaration"
```

I am facing this issue while integrating Angular firebase in my Angular 9 project.
[image: My application's package.json]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't share pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue and found this open issue in AngularFire GitHub repo. Downgrading to 6.0.0 did not work for me.  https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2521

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try changing target in the `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json`  from `es5` to `es2015`

Comment: If you set to ´es2015´ it won´t work for IE 11, as you can see in this post https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-and-internet-explorer-a6e4b5a5dae1

Comment: @apaternina it's time to stop supprt IE 11. Even Microsoft tends to do it: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666

Comment: But does this solution really work? I'm facing same issue for `OwlDateTimeIntl`. It says:-  `Error on worker #2: Error: getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected OwlDateTimeIntl to have an inner class declaration
    at Esm5ReflectionHost.getInternalNameOfClass`

Comment: This did not work for me in ng9 too. @iLoveUnicorns postinstall worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733064/error-in-getinternalnameofclass-called-on-a-non-es5-class-expected-angularfi#answer-63727427

Comment: This did not work from me in ng 9. Here is the open issue https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/261

Answer (score 54):

I encountered same issue during migration from Angular8 to Angular9.

In Angular9 they introduced new generation compilation and rendering pipeline called Angular Ivy. The documentation says:

> Ivy applications can be built with libraries that were created with the View Engine compiler. This compatibility is provided by a tool known as the Angular compatibility compiler (ngcc). CLI commands run ngcc as needed when performing an Angular build.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/ivy

So in order to project with `"target": "es5"` work, after using `npm install` you have to run ngcc.

You can add it in your package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
}
```

Then it should run automaticly after running `npm install`.

Comment: Although the accepted answer works,for few dependent external modules where `es2015` is actually required changing it will not work. This did.

Comment: Your answer allowed me to understand the problem came from Ivy, so I simply disabled it with angularCompilerOptions/enableIvy: false. Obviously we'll have to upgrade the whole project to Ivy one day, but for now, it works.

Comment: The solution worked fine, but I needed to use the `--unsafe-perm` flag (`npm install --unsafe-perm`), since the build process is being runned as root. `--unsafe-perm` was mentioned by Yassine Khachlek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136746/npm-install-failed-with-cannot-run-in-wd). More about `--unsafe-perm` [here](https://geedew.com/What-does-unsafe-perm-in-npm-actually-do/).

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the following in tsconfig.json:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
  }
```

Not ideal but it worked.

Adding

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
```

to package.json and changing `target` to `es2015` in tsconfig.json didn't work - probably some other setting(s) messing with them.